# Objective-c: find the last index of an element in a NSArray

Tags: objective-c, find, nsarray

I have a NSArray, and I want to find the last occurrence of an element.
For example:

```
[apple, oranges, pears, apple, bananas];
int i = lastIndexOf("apple");
out: i == 3;
```

I'm struggling to find a simple solution looking an the APIS, but there aren't example so it's pretty hard to understand which function I should use.

Comment: You do realise that you have "apple" singular and "apples" plural in your array. Is that desired or is it a typo?

Comment: @Zaph this was going to be my solution, but I was looking for something in the API.

Comment: @Daniel: it wasn't desired, I will edit apples to apple

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
    passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        return [@"apples" isEqualToString:obj];
    }];
```

If the array doesn't contain `@"apples"`, `index` will be `NSNotFound`.

Comment: I guess that the NSUInteger is going to be < 0 if there is no "apple" in the array. "passingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop)" this part is the one which I don't understand, a link or an explanation would be welcome

Comment: In this case you don't need `i` and `stop`, if you was doing something more complex then you may need to use these. This is a block which will be invoked for each item in your array. If it returns `YES`, then it stops and `index` will have the value of the last `i`, if no objects march, then `index` will be `NSNotFound`. I added a link to the documentation on my answer

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` has `indexOfObjectWithOptions:passingTest:`, this will allow you to search in reverse.

For example:

```
NSArray *myArr = @[@"apple", @"oranges", @"pears", @"apple", @"bananas"];
NSString *target = @"apple";

NSUInteger index = [myArr indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
                                      passingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                          return [target isEqualToString:obj];
                                      }];
```

You can find out more details of this method in the [Documentation by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Comment: @Richard Why isn't it a good idea, especially in such a simple case. I suggest that the simplest code is the best unless/until it is proven to be to slow by demonstration and then profiling.

Comment: @Daniel His example array isn't sorted, so `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` would be a bad choice.

Comment: I added a comment to the answer of rob

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a reusable method with categories, I had written one for lastIndexOf.

Code can be found and freely used from here -

http://www.tejasshirodkar.com/blog/2013/06/nsarray-lastindexof-nsmutablearray-lastindexof/